# while running mapreduce program on cluster,input path was regarded as output path

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

When I run map-reduce program on cluster, input path was regarded as an output path, so I alwalys got a error about

> output directory already exists.

But when I ignore the arguments of `DriverClass`, the program runs successfully.
I really don't know why this happened. And I can run this program in IntelliJ IDEA, I get the right answer in local environment.

I didn't make wrong with the input path's index and output's

```
FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job,new Path(args[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job,new Path(args[1]));
```

HDFS structure

[image]

and my hadoop command and error msg below

[image]

but, after I ignore the `DriverClass` args, the program run successfully

[image]

Comment: Please post outputs of console as text

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with:

```
FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job,new Path(args[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job,new Path(args[1]));
```

`args[0]` is actually the class name, and so you want to use `args[1]` for input and `args[2]` for output.